# Does adding to a method group count as using a variable?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have the following code example taken from the code of a `Form`:

```
    protected void SomeMethod()
    {
        SomeOtherMethod(this.OnPaint);
    }

    private void SomeOtherMethod(Action<PaintEventArgs> onPaint)
    {
        onPaint += MyPaint;
    }

    protected void MyPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // paint some stuff
    }
```

The second method (`SomeOtherMethod`) has resharper complaining at me.  It says of `onPaint` that *"Value assigned is not used in any execution path"*.

To my mind it was used because I added a method to the list of methods called when a paint was done.

But usually when resharper tells me something like this it is because I am not understanding some part of C#.  Like maybe when the param goes out of goes out of scope the item I added to the list gets removed (or something like that).

I thought I would ask here to see if any one knows what resharper is trying to tell me.

(Side Note: I usually just override OnPaint.  But I am trying to get OnPaint to call a method in another class.  I don't want to expose that method publicly so I thought I would pass in the OnPaint group and add to it.)

Comment: Frankly, I had no idea that `Action` had a `+=` operator. That's wild.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: All delegates define a "+" operator. The sum of two delegates is a third delegate which when invoked, calls the two addends. Since there is a + operator, there is also a += operator.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: These things I should have known for so long, and yet I learn something new every day. Thanks for the added details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is correct. Consider the following:

```
int X;
int Y;
void SomeMethod()
{         
    SomeOtherMethod(this.X);
}      
void SomeOtherMethod(int x)
{
    x += this.Y;
}
```

Here the code modifies formal parameter x, and then never uses the modified x.  This does not modify "this.X"

You've done the same thing with the delegate. You modify the formal parameter and then never use the result; the original "OnPaint" is unchanged, just as "X" is unchanged in my example.

Remember, just because a delegate is a *reference type* does not mean that you're passing around a reference to a *variable* when you pass around an *instance*. You're passing a reference to an instance, not a reference to the storage location of that instance.

Answer (score 5):

Does it work at all? I don't expect that MyPaint is ever called. That would be a clue.

It seems to me that `onPaint += MyPaint;` would have no effect outside this method. `onPaint` is a parameter (local variable), and the changes are lost when the method exits. And that is why you get the warning.

To see why, you would have needed something like a `ref` parameter, but you can't call that  with an event (this.Onpaint):

```
// not applicable
private void SomeOtherMethod(ref Action<PaintEventArgs> onPaint)
{
   onPaint += MyPaint;
}
```

Comment: Henk: Action is a multicast delegate, so that does have an effect.  You can combine multicast delegates this way (though it's very odd to do so for anything other than event backing stores...)

Comment: @Reed: But `onPaint` is a _Copy_, isn't it?

Comment: @Reed, yes, the key was in the small 'o' in onPaint, I edited.

Answer (score 5):

Delegates are immutable, so combining creates a copy.  When you call:

```
private void SomeOtherMethod(Action<PaintEventArgs> onPaint)
```

You're actually creating a modified *copy* of the original `Action<PaintEventArgs>`.

That being said, I would personally avoid trying to work this way, unless there is a very compelling reason to do so.

Personally, I would consider making an interface which exposes an `OnPaint` event, and passing the interface into this method.  You could then subscribe to the event.  This would have the same effect you're trying to achieve, but be much more clear.

In this case, I would just have your other class subscribe to the [Paint event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) on the Control directly.

Comment: Not entirely true, it's still a reference to the original `onPaint` (you can see this if you return it and compare references). However, all delegate operations (like `+=`) *do* make copies, which results in this behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Delegates are immutable. You can't change them. They're a bit like strings in that respect. Imagine your method was:

```
private void SomeOtherMethod(string x)
{
    x += "hello";
}
```

Again, that would be a pointless method. The original string wouldn't have changed - you'd just have changed the value of the local variable (the parameter) to refer to a different string. The exact same thing happens in your delegate case.

*Either* you need to pass the variable by reference *or* you need to change your whole design.

See my article on [delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more about how delegate combining works.

Comment: Proof: `var oldOnPaint = onPaint; onPaint += MyPaint; Debug.Assert(oldOnPaint == onPaint);`

Answer (score 2):

After doing some experiments, I think the reason is that when you do a `+=` on an `Action`, you are not modifying the initial value, but rather the local variable itself. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    Action<int> doSomething = OnClick;
    doSomething += i=> Console.WriteLine("test");
    OnClick(1);
}

private void OnClick(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
}
```

... simply yields "clicked".

So the MyPaint method in your example is not being modified, only the onPaint variable. Since you don't do anything with that variable after the `+=`, there was no point doing the `+=` in the first place.

**Edit**

Porges points out that since OnClick is a method (not a delegate), this example isn't quite accurate. Here's a better one:

```
Action<int> doSomething = i => Console.WriteLine("test");
var doSomething2 = doSomething; 
doSomething2 += i => Console.WriteLine("test2");
doSomething(1);
```

Output: `test`

Comment: The reasoning is correct, but the example is incorrect. You're calling the method `OnClick` directly.

Comment: @Porges: I intentionally called OnClick directly, to show that `doSomething +=...` does not actually modify OnClick itself. By the same logic, `onPaint += ...` does not actually modify `this.OnPaint` in the question's code sample, which is what the OP said he expected to happen.

Comment: But OnClick isn't a delegate (like onPaint is). To reproduce the example properly, you should make another delegate: `var doSomething2 = doSomething; doSomething2 += i => Console.WriteLine("test2");` then call `doSomething(1)`.